# CSS Display None - Hide

Tags: html, css, html-table, coldfusion

At a loss here. Have similar code working...

Cannot get hidden td or when changed to div it doesn't show either...
This is not a coldfusion problem I don't think...

Required Javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function showElement(layer){
  var myLayer = document.getElementById(layer);
  if(myLayer.style.display=="none"){
  myLayer.style.display="block";
  myLayer.backgroundPosition="top";
  } else { 
 myLayer.style.display="none";
  }
  }
 </script>
```

This Cold Fusion Code all works fine and displays fine in tables...
When I add the function to hide it - I can't get it to display...
The typeid is different each time...

```
 <table cellpadding=2 cellspacing=2 align=center border=1>
<cfoutput query=list group="typeid">
    <cfquery name="gl" datasource="#ds#">
    select * from shindates
    where sdate <= #monthdate# and stime >= #createODBCDateTime(timenow)# and typeid = '#typeid#'
    order by typeid, sdate
    </cfquery>
    <cfquery name="type" datasource="#ds#">
    select * from type
    where typeid = '#typeid#'
    </cfquery>
    <tr>
    <td><img src="../images/edit.png" alt="Edit" width=25 border=0 alt="Show List" onclick="javascript:showElement('#typeid#')"></td>
    <td valign=middle class=verd10>#type.type#</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan=2 id="#typeid#" style="display: none">

        <cfloop query="gl">
        <table cellpadding=5 cellspacing=5 align=center class=general>
        <tr>
        <td colspan=2>
        #type.type# - #Dateformat(gl.sdate, 'dddd - mmm dd, yyyy')# - #Timeformat(gl.stime, 'HH:mm')#<br>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <cfset csigned = signedup + gsignedup>
        <cfif csigned is not 0>
        <td class=verd9 align=center><b>Unable to Cancel - Users Signed Up</b></td>
        <td class=verd9 align=center>
        <cfform action="adminmanage.cfm?shinid=#gl.shinid#" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Manage List" class="legal8">
        <input type="hidden" value="#gl.shinid#" name="shinid">
        </cfform>
        </td>
        <cfelse>
        <td class=verd9 align=center>
        <cfform action="adminlist.cfm?src=del" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Cancel" class="legal8">
        <input type="hidden" value="#gl.shinid#" name="shinid">
        </cfform>
        </td>
        <td class=verd9 align=center>
        <cfform action="adminmanage.cfm?shinid=#gl.shinid#" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Manage List" class="legal8">
        <input type="hidden" value="#gl.shinid#" name="shinid">
        </cfform>
        </td>
        </cfif>
        </tr>
        </table>

        </cfloop>
</td>
</tr>       
</cfoutput>
</table>
```

Any help appreciated...

Comment: Shouldn't `myLayer.backgroundPosition="top";` be `myLayer.style.backgroundPosition="top";`?

Comment: No luck - doesn't change things. Doesn't affect other coding using similar javascript element.

Comment: If it isn't a CF problem, show the generated HTML, not the CFML source!

Comment: p.s. as it stands this code is potentially vulnerable to both SQL and JS injection. You should be using [cfqueryparam](http://cfdocs.org/cfqueryparam) in the queries, and [HtmlEditFormat](http://cfdocs.org/HtmlEditFormat) and [JsStringFormat](http://cfdocs.org/JsStringFormat) in the output!

Comment: As Peter said - we need the HTML generated by this code - not just the CF code. CFFORM is going to add a bunch of machine generated JS as well. Also - does firebug or chrome dev tools give you a JS error to work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your JavaScript and it seems to work fine in the following simplified example:

```
<table cellpadding=2 cellspacing=2 align=center border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x25" border=0 alt="Show List" onclick="showElement('#typeid#')">
        </td>
        <td valign=middle class=verd10>#type.type#</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2 id="#typeid#" style="display: none">The hidden content.</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
    function showElement(layer) {
        var myLayer = document.getElementById(layer);
        if (myLayer.style.display == "none") {
            myLayer.style.display = "table-cell";
            myLayer.backgroundPosition = "top";
        } else {
            myLayer.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

See first demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/BPWR8/

I also tested your HTML/ColdFusion snippet as is and the JavaScript still works.
See second demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/xK6jv/

Are you sure your JavaScript is in the page?

**Minor Point:** you might want to set display to `table-cell` instead of `block`.

Comment: No Luck - has to add javascript:showElement( to get test code to work - which worked... But as soon as I added the displayed desireable content "hidden" no go...

Answer (score 0):

ARRRGHHH

Seems it is coding way below what I am trying to do...

I do a CFABORT and all works...

Down below - I have a calendar function - pulling a date etc to plug into new entries...

Looks like it might be that...

Coding as presented by several here should work...

Thanx - my bad...

Comment: It sounds like you may want to close this question as the code above did not have issues.

Comment: .. or if it was just a localized issue (unlikely to be useful to others) you might want to delete the thread.